# Configure tab-switch hotkey in gnome-terminal

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I used to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> to switch between `gnome-terminal` tabs. In my recent 19.10 installation, this does not work. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, instead of switching tab, the command line shows this:

```
(arg: 1)
```

and if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, it becomes:

```
(arg: 12)
```

I checked the options in `gnome-terminal`, it is set to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> to switch between tabs.

I would like to know which application is hijacking the hotkey, and how to fix it.

PS. I do NOT want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug, tracked upstream at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/2174. As stated there, disabling header bar or disabling mnemonics are possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Can probably be worked around by creating a new keymapping with an app like `xkeysnail`. I contributed code to it recently to enable <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality.

https://github.com/mooz/xkeysnail

Also I make use of it in my own project that remaps <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>... all while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is positioned in the <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> key positions. If that isn't confusing then just sum it up to say it works like a Mac now. Also <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is remapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> essentially, unless it is the terminal. Then, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> really is control and no special remapping occurs on that particular key.

https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto

A short example of some remapping I do with it.

```
define_keymap(None,{
    # Cmd Tab - App Switching Default
    # App switching is mapped to use Ctrl+F13 in place of Tab
    # this avoids Alt+Tab from still activating App Switching
    # Ctrl+Tab is also used for In-App tab switching often times
    # RCtrl is also mapped in Cmd key position only
    K("RC-Tab"): K("RC-F13"),
    K("RC-Shift-Tab"): K("RC-Shift-F13"),
    K("RC-Grave"): K("RC-Shift-F13"),
    # In-App Tab switching
    # K("M-Tab"): K("C-Tab"),                   # Chromebook - In-App Tab switching
    # K("M-Shift-Tab"): K("C-Shift-Tab"),       # Chromebook - In-App Tab switching
    K("Super-Tab"): K("LC-Tab"),                # Default
    K("Super-Shift-Tab"): K("LC-Shift-Tab"),    # Default
    K("LC-Grave") : K("LC-Shift-Tab"),
})
```